# What is difference between TLSv1_1_method, TLSv1_1_server_method and TLSv1_1_client_method

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I looked at the official document of openssl, the link is below:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/SSLv3_method.html

but can't find information what is different between all these 3 methods. From the name I can understand that from client side I should use TLSv1_1_client_method and from the server side TLSv1_1_server_method, but what for TLSv1_1_method then?

Comment: TLSv1_1_server_method for server only type, TLSv1_1_client_method is client only type whereas TLSv1_1_method is generic type, you can call it regardless if your module is TLS server or client

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The think is the handshake stuck when I call TLSv1_1_method on client side, but it pass when I call TLSv1_1_client_method. So I guess there may be some difference during handshake?